# Is the Rebel base in the 'Rogue One' trailer the one on Yavin IV?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In the [teaser](https://youtu.be/Wji-BZ0oCwg) for *Rogue One* we see some shots inside a hangar and in a control room (with Mon Mothma).  It looks a lot like the hidden base from *Episode IV*.

**Is this just an homage to the design, or is it meant to be the same base?**

Comment: Pfft. It took me until about two days before the damn film comes out to properly answer this. I feel like a failure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update 2.** 
A screenshot directly from the film (complete with helpful subtitle).

[image]

---

**Update:** We now have proof-positive from the Mexican Rogue One publicity poster that the base in the film is indeed Yavin. This is also backed up by a tweet from the film's original screenwriter, Gary Whitta.

> **[Whitta:](https://twitter.com/garywhitta/status/795686312401465345/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)** 
>   *Wow Mexico’s #RogueOne poster is heavy on the Yavin and appropriately gorgeous!*

[image]

<s>There's every indication that it's the **same base,** from the *highly distinctive* architecture, the equipment scattered about the base floor, the jerry-rigged drooping power conduits hanging from the ceiling and the low, oblong opening front door.</s>

### Rogue One

[image]

### A New Hope

[image]

[image]

Mon Mothma's command chamber also seems to be identical (note the vine-covered stone walls behind the map screens)

### A New Hope

[image]

### Rogue One

[image]

Comment: Just realised it is the same place as is used in the cast photo https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One#/media/File%3ARogue_One_cast_revealed.jpg more detail of the hanger there.

Comment: @JeremyFrench - Although it's not that I don't appreciate the acceptance, but you might want to hold fire until there's a *definitive* confirmation from the cast, crew, script or novelisation

Comment: OK shall do. For the moment.

Answer (score 5):

Actually I realised of course they are...
From Episode IV opening crawl

> It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, **striking from a hidden base**, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.
>   During the battle, Rebel spies managed to steal secret plans to the Empire's ultimate weapon, the DEATH STAR

And from Episode V

> It is a dark time for the Rebellion. Although the Death Star has been destroyed, Imperial troops have driven the Rebel forces from **their hidden base** and pursued them across the galaxy.

So I'm pretty sure canonically they are the same.

Comment: Maybe, but this is poor evidence.  The base in Episode V is definitely not the base from Episode IV.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - True, but the base they're referring to in the both crawls are the same.

Comment: Is your first line supposed to say "Episode **IV**" (=4, VI = 6)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks fixed.